# google compute engine load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I created a HTTP Load Balancer in Google Compute Engine and gave it a name. But I am not able to access the application by that name. But it works fine with the corresponding mapped IP. So accessing the application via IP is working but I am not sure what would be the right Load balancer name. ( for example in Azure you get .trafficmanager.net and similarly you get a load balancer name in AWS also. 
Does Google Cloud support IPV6 . What would be the IP or dns name to access because I just see IPV4 address.

Thanks,
TNB

Comment: You are more likely to get answers if you have only one query per question post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about internal DNS for load balancers, but I do know that Google compute engine [does not support IPv6](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking?hl=en#networks).